# Downloaded file showing zero bytes in S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, socialengine

I have given complete permission to the file.And downloading it from php code...In this manner...

```
 while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
  ob_end_clean();
}
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode(basename($filepath)), true);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary", true);
header("Content-Type: application/force-download", true);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream", true);
header("Content-Type: application/download", true);
header("Content-Description: File Transfer", true);
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filepath), true);
flush();

$fp = fopen($filepath, "r");
while (!feof($fp)) {
  echo fread($fp, 65536);
  // ob_clean();
  flush();
}
fclose($fp);
```

But the downloaded file is showing zerobytes.Im unable to get an perfect answer for this could you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please comment below line in your code and try it again

> header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filepath), true);